# Where is a checkbox "include interface callbacks" when you want to create new fragment in android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, interface, callback, android-studio-3.6

I just upgraded my android studio at 3.6.3 version and I started to watch some Udemy course about Kotlin programming and I noticed when I tried to create new Fragment I didn't see a checkbox "include interface callbacks" as in old version in Android studio.
I am a beginner in Kotlin so I need some advice.

Here is an example of fragment creation in the new Android studio:
[image]

Here is in some old version:
[image]

How can I include interface callbacks in the new version of the Android studio automatically?
I hope I don't need to do it all manually, maybe some shortcut option?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated and I found out that interface callbacks for communication between fragments and fragments with activity are now maintained with the use of **ViewModel class** which is much easier than using all that code with interface callbacks.

Second good option for such communication is the use of third-party libraries like **RxJava**.
Means guys from Google and JetBrains removed that option and now is available option to create ViewModel class within Fragment through File -> New -> Fragment -> Fragment(with ViewModel).